# Show that exists one $G$-isomorphism between $X$ and $G/Stab_G(X)$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, stabilizer

> Let $G$ be a group if $G$ acts transitively on a finite set $X$ then exists one $G$-isomorphism between $X$ and $G/Stab_G(X)$

I try to use the action of $G$ in $G/Stab_G(x)$ giving by left multiplication and i define $f:x \rightarrow G/ Stab_G(x)$ define by $f(y)=gStab_G(x)$ where $g\circ y=x$ this $g$ exists because $G$ acts transitively, and i proof that $f$ is one to one and clearly is onto.

I try to elaborate one conmutative diagram but i not sure of these way is correct.
Any hint or help i will be very grateful.

Comment: Note ${\rm Stab}(x)$ is only well-defined up to conjugacy, since ${\rm Stab}(gx)=g{\rm Stab}(x)g^{-1}$. When you say there exists "one" isomorphism, it suggests you mean "only one" isomorphism exists, which is not true.

Comment: "$Stab_G(X)$" or "$Stab_G(x)$"? You used both, but they are not the same thing.